# Select multiple element affecting properties of the objects it's populated from

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

So I have this array **people**

```
people = [{name: "John",hair: false},{name: "James": hair: false}]
```

I have a **select** element with the **multiple** attribute that is populated from

```
 <select ng-model="people" multiple
         ng-options="person.hair as person.name for person in people">
 </select>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when the user selects one or more items from this select element it will set the hair property of the selected item(s) to `true`.

Now what's happening is I select an item and it sets `people` to `false`, which makes sense. The select needs an `ng-model` for `ng-options` to work. If I set it to something else nothing gets changed on `people`

I've tried putting a function in `ng-change` and throwing the `ng-model` I set to it but that won't make the selection 'highlighted' in the select multiple element. I know there are more practical ways to do this but I'd like to figure out how to use the select multiple if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
<select ng-model="hairyPersons" multiple
        ng-change="updatePeople(hairyPersons)"
        ng-options="person as person.name for person in people">
</select>
```

```js
$scope.updatePeople = function(selects) {
    $scope.people.forEach(x => x.hair=false);
    selects.forEach(x => x.hair=true);
};
```

The `ng-model` variable needs to be different than the `ng-options` array.

## [The DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/akTz89djWdew9sqB1ez2?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [
    {name: "John", hair: false},
    {name: "James", hair: false},
    {name: "Mary", hair: false},
    {name: "Fred", hair: false},
  ];
  $scope.updatePeople = function(selects) {
    $scope.people.forEach(x => x.hair=false);
    selects.forEach(x => x.hair=true);
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
     <select ng-model="hairyPersons" multiple
         ng-change="updatePeople(hairyPersons)"
         ng-options="person as person.name for person in people">
     </select>
     <div ng-repeat="p in people">
       {{p.name}} hair={{p.hair?'TRUE':false}}
     </div>
     <h3>hairyPersons</h3>
     <ol>
       <li ng-repeat="h in hairyPersons">{{h.name}}</li>
     </ol>
</body>
```

---

Another way to do it is with a list of checkboxes:

```
<div ng-repeat="p in people">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="p.hair">{{p.name}}<br>
</div>
```

The `ng-model` directives operate directly on objects in the `people` array.

All the unchecked boxes set `hair: false`; all the checked boxes set `hair: true` on their respective objects.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. Also appreciate you editing the formatting on my post.